# Laravel Nova Resource, combine fields in layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel and Nova, I have a Collection resource which has multiple fields, now when you define the fields for example:

```
Text::make('Meta 1 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 1 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 2 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 2 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 3 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 3 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 4 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
Text::make('Meta 4 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
```

Each field will take up one row, in the html.

[image: with]

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to have custom layout options (without having to make a full blown custom Tool), so that it's possible for example to group a few text fields in a div. **and have the label and value field on one line**

**Pseudo Code**

```
<div class="flex">
    Text::make('Meta 1 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
    Text::make('Meta 1 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
</div>
<div class="flex">
    Text::make('Meta 2 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
    Text::make('Meta 2 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        new Panel('Group 1', $this->group1()),
        new Panel('Group 2', $this->group2()),
    ];
}

protected function group1()
{
    return [
        Text::make('Meta 1 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
        Text::make('Meta 1 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
    ];
}

protected function group2()
{
    return [
        Text::make('Meta 2 Label')->hideFromIndex(),
        Text::make('Meta 2 Value')->hideFromIndex(),
    ];
}
```

Check [field-panels](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#field-panels) laravel nova doc section for more information.